# The funniest English mistranslations that you've ever heard

Tags: mistranslation

I live in Indonesia and English is not a primary language here but the Indonesia education system stipulates English as a compulsory subject. Therefore, most of Indonesians have learnt English since they were in elementary school yet a lot of words in English have mistranslated here, some are considered as jokes. When my friends and I learned English for the first time, we translated **DOORMAT** as **WELCOME** just because of this

[image]

I thought that was funny. **:D**

My question is what is the funniest English mistranslations (words, phrases, or sentences) that you've ever heard?

Comment: Regrettably, this falls into "What's your favourite..." which is explicitly [off-topic](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: That *is* really funny, and a good story! As I was typing, @AndrewLeach posted a relevant comment. Please do keep us in mind for questions you have about English. I do like your story, though.

Comment: You can post this sort of questions in Quora. The Quora community happily answers such questions. Quora can be accessed at this http://www.quora.com